# Is there a way to generate galleries in posts in wordpress automatically?

Tags: wordpress

I am importing RSS feed from a Tumblr blog to Wordpress. It checks for new Tumblr posts every 2 hours and copies them as Wordpress posts. They are exclusively collections of images, and the importer does not have options of how to render posts. I don't want to style these posts individually. Is there a way that these auto-generated posts could be displayed as galleries upon import?

Comment: You mean photos within the posts as galleries? I think it is doable, if you have those photos in the Media library first, then you can feed the ids of those photos into [gallery ids="1,2,3"] gallery shortcode and it will be native WP gallery...

Comment: Good call. And I could probably just put the shortcode into the post creation script?

Comment: Great if it works for you. I post this idea as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Photos within the posts to display as galleries.

First You have to make sure those photos are uploaded/added into the Media library in WordPress so each photo will be assigned as ID.

Then you can feed the ids of those photos into WP native gallery
short-code e.g.  **[gallery ids="1,2,3"]**

It will make those photos display as native WP supported photo galleries. You might need to add some styling in your theme to make gallery's look and feel on the front-end as per your requirements.